# How to output MVC / C# object to Javascript object?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, client-side

I have a C# model that gets populated through its constructor. I would like to place this object in my _Layout.cshtml so my Javascript can use it as settings.

Here is what my model looks like:

```
public class SomeConfig
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }

    public SomeConfig()
    {
        PropertyA = SystemSettings.getSetting(KEYA);
        PropertyB = SystemSettings.getSetting(KEYB);
        PropertyC = SystemSettings.getSetting(KEYC);
    }
}
```

I would like to initialize and output this in _Layout.cshtml so all my other views can use it. So far I am only able to figure out how to do this manually in _Layout.cshtml like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyNamespace.someConfig = {
        PropertyA: @SystemSettings.getSetting(KEYA),
        PropertyB: @SystemSettings.getSetting(KEYB),
        PropertyC: @SystemSettings.getSetting(KEYC)
    }
</script>
```

This is horrible because every time the SomeConfig.cs model gets extended, I have to remember to extend it manually client-side. Is there a way to initialize it in the _Layout.cshtml so it creates a Javascript object dynamically?

Comment: Json.Net is pretty good........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try instead to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyNamespace.someConfig =  @Json.Encode(SystemSettings);
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to add Html.Raw(..) in front of it and worked great. Thanks!